How can i make Textures with code in Godot4?
I am making my own Tetris in Godot (it does not matter), I am new and I still don't understand how to use textures. I wanted to have personalizabled color brick and because I did not know how to do that with textures, I ended up using the basic draw_rect() or draw_polygon() method.
But now I am doing things more complexe I want to use textures instead, for easier comprehension and more readabilty.
So my question is, can I make textures with code. Like using the function draw, but to draw on a texture and re use it later.
I tried many things but I still being blocked, finding the answer will help me :) Thanks

Well it depends if you want to use a sprite for your game since I assume you're making it in 2d but another ways to do this is that in 3d you can make a 3d material and that can be used to apply it to anything you want as a texture.Also as to my knowledge there is no way to make a texture using code but you can still make it with the editor. Hope this helps!
